# Extract rows based on conditions Pandas Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, rows

I need to extract rows if certain conditions are applied.

1. the column `col1` should contain all the words in the list `list_words`.
2. the last word should be `Story`
3. the last word in the next row should b `ac`:

This is my current code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['Draft SW Quality Assurance Story', 'alex ac', 'anny ac', 'antoine ac','aze epic', 'bella ac', 'Complete SW Quality Assurance Plan Story', 'celine ac','wqas epic', 'karmen ac', 'kameilia ac', 'Update SW Quality Assurance Plan Story', 'joseph ac','Update SW Quality Assurance Plan ac', 'joseph ac'],
                   'col2': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd','ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh', 'ii', 'jj', 'kk', 'll', 'mm', 'nn', 'oo']}) 
print(df)

list_words="SW Quality Plan Story"
set_words = set(list_words.split())
#check if list_words is in the cell
df['TrueFalse']=pd.concat([df.col1.str.contains(word,regex=False) for word in list_words.split()],axis=1).sum(1) > 1 

print('\n',df)
#extract last word
df["Suffix"] = df["col1"].str.split().str[-1]
print('\n',df)
df['ok']=''
for i in range (len(df)-1):
    if ((df["Suffix"].iloc[i]=='Story') & (df["TrueFalse"].iloc[i]=='True') & (df["Suffix"].iloc[i+1]=='ac')):
        df['ok'].iloc[i+1]=df["Suffix"].iloc[i+1]

print('\n',df)
```

output:

```
                                         col1 col2  TrueFalse Suffix ok
0           Draft SW Quality Assurance Story   aa       True  Story   
1                                    alex ac   bb      False     ac   
2                                    anny ac   cc      False     ac   
3                                 antoine ac   dd      False     ac   
4                                   aze epic   ee      False   epic   
5                                   bella ac   ff      False     ac   
6   Complete SW Quality Assurance Plan Story   gg       True  Story   
7                                  celine ac   hh      False     ac   
8                                  wqas epic   ii      False   epic   
9                                  karmen ac   jj      False     ac   
10                               kameilia ac   kk      False     ac   
11    Update SW Quality Assurance Plan Story   ll       True  Story   
12                                 joseph ac   mm      False     ac   
13       Update SW Quality Assurance Plan ac   nn       True     ac   
14                                 joseph ac   oo      False     ac
```

**line 13** should be set to `False`

desired output :

```
                                        col1 col2  TrueFalse Suffix     
1   Complete SW Quality Assurance Plan Story   gg      True  Story   
2                                  celine ac   hh      True  ac   
3    Update SW Quality Assurance Plan Story    ll      True  Story   
4                                 joseph ac    mm      True  ac
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are your all different conditions, and their intersection:

```
# Condition 1: all words in col1 minus all words in set_words must be empty
df["condition_1"] = df.col1.apply(lambda x: not bool(set_words - set(x.split())))

# Condition 2: the last word should be 'Story'
df["condition_2"] = df.col1.str.endswith("Story") 

# Condition 3: the last word in the next row should be ac. See `shift(-1)`
df["condition_3"] = df.col1.str.endswith("ac").shift(-1) 

# When all three conditions meet: new column 'conditions'
df["conditions"] = df.condition_1 & df.condition_2 & df.condition_3

# Back to your notation:
# TrueFalse: rows that fulfill all three conditions along with their next rows
df["TrueFalse"] = df.conditions | df.conditions.shift(1)                                                                                         
df["Suffix"] = df.col1.apply(lambda x: x.split()[-1])
```

Now your desired output:

```
>>> print(df[["col1", "col2", "TrueFalse", "Suffix"]][df.TrueFalse])
                                        col1 col2  TrueFalse Suffix
6   Complete SW Quality Assurance Plan Story   gg       True  Story
7                                  celine ac   hh       True     ac
11    Update SW Quality Assurance Plan Story   ll       True  Story
12                                 joseph ac   mm       True     ac
```

FYI, all the dataframe:

```
>>> print(df[["col1", "col2", "TrueFalse", "Suffix"]])                                                                                                       
                                        col1 col2  TrueFalse Suffix
0           Draft SW Quality Assurance Story   aa      False  Story
1                                    alex ac   bb      False     ac
2                                    anny ac   cc      False     ac
3                                 antoine ac   dd      False     ac
4                                   aze epic   ee      False   epic
5                                   bella ac   ff      False     ac
6   Complete SW Quality Assurance Plan Story   gg       True  Story
7                                  celine ac   hh       True     ac
8                                  wqas epic   ii      False   epic
9                                  karmen ac   jj      False     ac
10                               kameilia ac   kk      False     ac
11    Update SW Quality Assurance Plan Story   ll       True  Story
12                                 joseph ac   mm       True     ac
13       Update SW Quality Assurance Plan ac   nn      False     ac
14                                 joseph ac   oo      False     ac
```

Comment: in line 7, shouldn't condition_3 be set to true?

Comment: At line 7, `celine ac` is followed by `wqas epic` (line 8) which finishes by `ic`, and not `ac`, so condition 3 must be false. Or did I misunderstand your third condition?

Comment: the third condition should be true only if `story` is followed by `ac`

Comment: No, from your question, third condition is that the last word in next row is `ac`. What you suggest here (`story` followed by `ac`) is second and third condition together: `df.condition_2 & df.condition_3` that would keep only indices 0, 6 and 11 indeed.

Comment: yes, sorry
condition_2 and condition_3 should be combined

Comment: @A.khou I updated the whole naming, and now it fits your desired output! Tell me about it.

Comment: it worked perfectly, but I have a question please, would it work if I have two `ac` in a row. I didn't mention this in the question but can I extract every row that ends with  `ac` when I have a row that ends with  `story`

Comment: @A.khou sorry but I'll be honest here: I did my best to answer all of your updates already, regardless of how confusing the question was in the first place. It works: you could accept the answer. If your required output is now different, it's worth another question. Otherwise this is never ending. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you can accomplish this.

Pd.concat and use of .all to check if all the words are present.

Check if the same columns endswith story.

Check if the next column (df.shift(-1)) ends with ac.

Edit: After reading some comments it appears that you also want the next line that ends in ac to be True.

I added additional code at the end to add this condition.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['Draft SW Quality Assurance Story', 'alex ac', 'anny ac', 'antoine ac','aze epic', 'bella ac', 'Complete SW Quality Assurance Plan Story', 'celine ac','wqas epic', 'karmen ac', 'kameilia ac', 'Update SW Quality Assurance Plan Story', 'joseph ac','Update SW Quality Assurance Plan ac', 'joseph ac'],
                   'col2': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd','ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh', 'ii', 'jj', 'kk', 'll', 'mm', 'nn', 'oo']}) 
print(df)

list_words="SW Quality Plan Story"
set_words = set(list_words.split())
#check if list_words is in the cell
df['TrueFalse']=(pd.concat([df['col1'].str.contains(word) for word in set_words],axis=1).all(axis=1)) & (df['col1'].str.endswith('Story')) & (df['col1'].shift(-1).str.endswith('ac'))

##Make sure line ends with ac and prev line follows conditions
df['AC_COL'] = df['TrueFalse'].shift(1).fillna(False)
df['Final_TrueFalse'] = df['TrueFalse'] | df['AC_COL']
print(df[['col1','col2','Final_TrueFalse']])

                                                         col1 col2  Final_TrueFalse
0           Draft SW Quality Assurance Story   aa            False
1                                    alex ac   bb            False
2                                    anny ac   cc            False
3                                 antoine ac   dd            False
4                                   aze epic   ee            False
5                                   bella ac   ff            False
6   Complete SW Quality Assurance Plan Story   gg             True
7                                  celine ac   hh             True
8                                  wqas epic   ii            False
9                                  karmen ac   jj            False
10                               kameilia ac   kk            False
11    Update SW Quality Assurance Plan Story   ll             True
12                                 joseph ac   mm             True
13       Update SW Quality Assurance Plan ac   nn            False
14                                 joseph ac   oo            False
```

Comment: but shouldn't the 7th and 12th lines be true?

Comment: How could they be true when they don't contain all words in `set_words`?

Comment: It seems like I didn't explain it well in the question, but the conditions are combined, the 1st row should contain all the words in `set_words` and the last word in the next row should b `ac`

Comment: How would that work for 7th line? It does not contain all the words in `set_words` and 8th line's last word is not `ac`.

Comment: the 6th line ends with `story` and the 7th line ends with `ac`